# Forwading URL Through Cloudflare API

Tags: api, cloudflare

I'm trying to create a page rule using Cloudflare's API to forward http to https. Unfortunately, I don't think the documentation is 100% clear on how to do this. Here is the JSON object I'm currently passing to the POST body:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target": "url",
      "constraint": {
        "operator": "matches",
        "value": "http://exampletest.com/*"
      }
    }
],
  "actions": [{
    "id": "forwarding_url",
    "value": "https://exampletest.com/$1"
  }]
}
```

and here is the message I'm getting back:

```
{
"success": false,
"errors": [
    {
        "code": 1004,
        "message": "Page Rule validation failed: See messages for details."
    }
],
"messages": [
    {
        "code": 1,
        "message": ".settings[0].url: This value should not be blank.",
        "type": null
    },
    {
        "code": 2,
        "message": ".settings[0].statusCode: This value should not be blank.",
        "type": null
    }
],
"result": null
```

}

So it seems like I need to have a settings object somewhere, but any way I try to add the settings, I'm getting the same message. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Here is Cloudflare's Documentation on the subject. Not sure if I might be missing something:

https://api.cloudflare.com/#page-rules-for-a-zone-create-page-rule

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, just figured this one out. It looks like this is the correct format:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target": "url",
      "constraint": {
        "operator": "matches",
        "value": "http://exampletest.com/*"
      }
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "id": "forwarding_url",
      "value": {
        "url": "https://www.exampletest.com/$1",
        "status_code": 301
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You should mark it as the answer then :-) Btw. this is literally the only place on the internet I've seen document how to create a redirect via the api.

Comment: You got it. Done!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a parameter - `"status":"active"` to actually activate the page rule or else you're just creating an inactive rule.

Cloudflare sets this as an optional parameter, but it is needed to activate the rule.

The updated version of this answer goes like this:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target": "url",
      "constraint": {
        "operator": "matches",
        "value": "http://exampletest.com/*"
      }
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "id": "forwarding_url",
      "value": {
        "url": "https://www.exampletest.com/$1",
        "status_code": 301
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": "active"
}
```